# Creating a second form page for a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

I have an Organization model that has_many users through affiliations.

And, in the form of the organization ( the standard edit ) I use semanting_form_for and semantic_fields_for to display the organization fields and affiliations fields.

But I wish to create a separete form just to handle the affiliations of a specific organization. I was trying to go to the Organization controller and create a an edit_team and update_team methods then on the routes create those pages, but it's getting a mess and not working.

am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create edit_team and update_team methods in controller and add them into routes.rb

```
#organizations_controller
def edit_team
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  @team = @organization.affiliations
end

def update_team
  # updating affiliations
end

#routes.rb
map.resources :organizations, :member => { :edit_team => :get, :update_team => :put }
```

and this is enough. So show errors why it isn't working.

Comment: I'm having a problem submiting the form.
I have this route
update_team_organization PUT    /organizations/:id/update_team(.:format)      {:controller=>"organizations", :action=>"update_team"}

And my form starts with :
<% semantic_form_for update_team_organization_path do |f| %>

The submit button should call the action update_team in the organization controller, but I get this error:
(see comment below )

Comment: ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to 1. Actions: create, current_user, current_user_session, destroy, edit, edit_team, index, logged_in?, login_required, new, redirect_to_target_or_default, show, update, and update_team):

The url in the browser is:
http://localhost:3000/organizations/1/edit_team

So he is pointing at the ID and not the action, that should be, update_team.

Comment: Fixed the problem with this:

<% semantic_form_for @organization, :url => { :action => "update_team" } do |f| %>